# tcl dom get attributes as a list

Tags: xml, xpath, tcl, tdom

```
<Testcases>
<Testcase tc_name="tc1">
  <Parameters>
    <Input_Arguments>tc1_arg1</Input_Arguments>                 
    <Input_Arguments>tc2_arg2</Input_Arguments>
  </Parameters>  
</Testcase>
<Testcase tc_name="tc2">
  <Parameters>
    <Input_Arguments>tc2_arg1</Input_Arguments>
    <Input_Arguments>tc2_arg2</Input_Arguments>
  </Parameters>  
</Testcase>
</Testcases>
```

Above is my xml, I want to use tdom to first read in all "tc_name" attributes as a tcl list. Then use each tc_name in the list to locate corresponding parameters. Please tell me how to do that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your headline says tcl dom but your question says tdom and it's tagged as tdom so I'll go for a majority decision and give a tdom answer - they are different packages!

First you need to parse the raw xml with

```
# Assumes that xmlText holds your raw XML
dom parse $xmlText doc
```

Now get a list of the tc_name nodes

```
set nodes [$doc selectNodes {Testcases/Testcase[@tc_name]}
```

Now cycle around those nodes accessing the Parameter nodes

```
foreach node $nodes {
    set params [$node selectNodes Parameters]
    foreach param $params {
        # Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Don't forget to get rid of the document once you've finished with it. (Note that this will happen automatically when the proc exits if you're doing it inside a proc.)

```
$doc delete
```

I'm not completely sure what it is you want to do finally, so here's a bit of code to output each argument, with its tc_name, one per line:

```
dom parse {<Testcases>
             <Testcase tc_name="tc1">
               <Parameters>
                 <Input_Arguments>tc1_arg1</Input_Arguments>                 
                 <Input_Arguments>tc2_arg2</Input_Arguments>
               </Parameters>  
             </Testcase>
             <Testcase tc_name="tc2">
               <Parameters>
                 <Input_Arguments>tc2_arg1</Input_Arguments>
                 <Input_Arguments>tc2_arg2</Input_Arguments>
               </Parameters>  
             </Testcase>
           </Testcases>
        } doc
foreach testcase [$doc selectNodes Testcases/Testcase] {
    set name [$testcase getAttribute tc_name]
    foreach arg [$testcase selectNodes Parameters/Input_Arguments] {
        foreach child [$arg childNodes] {
            puts stdout $name\ [$child nodeValue]
        }
    }
}
$doc delete;          # Tidy away the parsed document
```

I hope this gives enough pointers to things for you to be able to complete your task

Comment: Try `[$testcase @tc_name]` for a good shortcut for getting an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution which uses XPath.

```
package require tdom

proc getTestCases {xmlText} {
    # Get a list of <Testcase> nodes that have attribute tc_name
    set doc [dom parse $xmlText]
    set tcNodes [$doc selectNodes /Testcases/Testcase\[@tc_name\]]

    # For each <Testcase> node, get the tc_name attribute, then get the
    # arguments.
    set cases [dict create]
    foreach tcNode $tcNodes {
        set tcName [$tcNode @tc_name]
        set arguments {}
        foreach argNode [$tcNode selectNodes Parameters/Input_Arguments] {
            lappend arguments [$argNode text]
        }
        dict append cases $tcName $arguments
    }

    $doc delete
    return $cases
}

# Main

# Retrieve the XML text from a file
set f [open testcases.xml]
set xmlText [read $f]
close $f

# Retrieve the test cases and display them
set testCases [getTestCases $xmlText]
dict for {tcName argList} $testCases {
    puts "$tcName: $argList"
}
```

## Discussion

- The function `getTestCases` starts out by parsing the XML into a DOM document
- It then calls `selectNodes` and an XPath expression to retrieve a list of \ nodes
- For each node, it retrieves the *tc_name* attribute, along with arguments
- The return value is a `dict` object. For more information on `dict`, look up your Tcl manual.